# android best practice to put time-consumed logic in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm building android app with multiple fragments on one activity and looking for best practice to load content.
my structure is like this

```
Activity
---- home fragment
---- second fragment
---- third fragment
..
---- another fragments
```

where should i put logic that cost time to load data. i want to show default content of fragment with progress dialog or some loading things so user know the app is on preparing data.

looking at fragment lifecycle, i tried put onResume but my fragment not changing until the data is loaded (no default content show up)

UPDATE 1:
I have implement LiveData and have small issue.

```
model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
model.getResult().observe(this, result -> {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    loading.dismiss();
});

model.setValue("ok");
```

this code on my activity. if i put sleep inside the observe, my page will show up with loading view and disappear after 2 seconds. but if i put sleep inside the MainViewModel method like this one

```
public void setValue(String value){
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    result.postValue(value);
}
```

my app will wait 2 seconds and then new page will show up without loading view. Is this how LiveData works or i just miss something?

UPDATE 2:
i have implement with real code. i still get issue my page (mostly) not showing with loading view.

i have try put my load data code in activity and in modelView and both give result same, sometimes it show loading view then load data, sometimes it freeze and suddenly new page show up with the data already loaded

UPDATE 3:
not proper one but currently i put delay before it start load the data. here is the code
**DetailActivity**

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  Data data

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // start show loading view
    loading.show();
    
    // init ViewModel
    setHomeViewModel();
    
    // set fragment
    changePage(Config.PAGE_DETAIL_HOME);
    
    // i put delay bit here just to wait loading view to show up
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(this::startCompile, 200);
    
    // previously i start compile data by just call the method
    // startCompile();
  }

  private void setHomeViewModel() {
    homeViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);

    homeViewModel.getData().observe(this, result -> {
        data = result;
        loading.dismiss();
    });
  }

  private void startCompile() {
    // trigger to start homeViewModel to read and compile all data
  }

  public void changePage(String page) {
    // set fragment
  }
}
```

**HomeViewModel**

```
public class HomeViewModel extends BaseViewModel {
  private final MutableLiveData<Data> result = new MutableLiveData<>();

  public void startCompile(Realm realm, ContentData contentData) {
    // read and compile data
    
    result.postValue(resultData);
  }

  public LiveData<Data> getData() {
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: There are 3 things that you need to do, display the progress bar while the data is being loaded, once the data is loaded, update the livedata object using postValue or setValue depending on whether you are updating the value on the main thread or a background thread, then observe the value which is updated and update the view accordingly by hiding the progress bar and displaying the data on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MVVM architecture to build android apps(it is an officially recommended pattern for developing android apps by google).

Model - data class

View - No logic to fetch data in the display, it contains the logic to display the given data.

ViewModel - all data computation and the logic resides here

Another layer is the repository layer, which has the logic for storing and fetching data from database or API calls.

Instead of using onResume(), look for LiveData and how to use it.

So basically, when the data is loaded, LiveData will be updated which is then observed in the Fragment.

There is a method in the fragment that will be called when the value of LiveData is updated, and you can update your view in that method.

This is called observer pattern, and it is implemented by LiveData/

Reference links

MVVM - https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide

LiveData - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Android development beginner course by Google: https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps-with-kotlin--ud9012

Advance course: https://www.udacity.com/course/advanced-android-app-development--ud855

Comment: i'm new in this concept. i can't mark your question now. but vote up for give me starting point

Comment: You can check the following beginner-friendly projects to get started with the pattern, https://www.developingdeveloper.tech/home. Let me know if you have any issue

Comment: i found this too as sample project. https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/MVVM-Architecture-Android-Beginners

Comment: That also works, then you can also check out google codelabs and udacity course by Google, it is also a perfect start for beginners. I have updated the post with the links.

Comment: i have update my question. because i'm not using kotlin so i can't fully follow the sample code. i try livedata as on your answer. please check my update

Comment: Please post the code that you have written in activity, viewmodel and the function which is calling the API to fetch the data.

Comment: sorry for late reply. i just update it with my code. for now i just add some delay to make sure the loading view is appear before compiling data started. back to ViewModel, am i use it in right way or completely wrong?